# How to communicate with shellscript from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, web, node-modules

I have to assign a dynamic variable to shell script that should be changed from nodejs ie value should be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. I believe that a simple solution deploying the use of, [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Using Node.js's [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) I have produced this example:

shellscript

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello $DATA"
```

app.js

```js
const exec = require('child_process').exec

const myData = 'World'

const myShellScript = exec(`DATA=${myData} sh ./shellscript`)

myShellScript.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log(data)
})
myShellScript.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.error(data)
})
```

This enables you to pass the `myData` variable into the shell script.